# Falso positivo em .exe de software visual basic

Tags: sql-server, visual-basic-6, antivirus

sou nova no fórum, então peço desculpas se eu estiver repetindo um tópico (eu pesquisei na verdade e não encontrei nada que se parecesse com o problema que estou tendo). Enfim, vou explicar o que está acontecendo:

Eu fiz um desenvolvimento em Visual Basic 2013 juntamente com o banco de dados SQL Server, que criei dentro do programa. O software está pronto e funcionando perfeitamente. A questão é que quando eu crio o executável, seja ele através do Inno Setup, Install Creator Pro ou qualquer outro, e instalo em um computador que tenha um antivírus Psafe ou Avast, eles acusam vírus no software! Mas quando vão fazer o scanner do arquivo .exe, eles não encontram nada. Enquanto no antivírus da própria Microsoft não acusa vírus nenhum.

Fui pesquisar a respeito e encontrei que ao criar uma chave de registro nas propriedades do programa (dentro do Visual Basic) iria acabar com esse problema. Bem, eu criei a chave mas não funcionou.

Preciso por favor que alguém possa me orientar nisso, já que o software vai ficar disponível em um site para download e o receio é que os usuários achem que o mesmo esteja com vírus, sendo que na verdade é um falso positivo. Não sei o problema está em alguma linha de código ou se preciso ir as propriedades do programa e modificar alguma coisa lá, para que quando o usuário instale o .exe no computador dele, caso possua esses tipos de antivírus, não acuse como ameaça. 
Agradeço imensamente a atenção e qualquer ajuda é bem vinda! Obrigada!

Comment: Nesses casos, assinar digitalmente o software ajuda. Outra coisa é que a detecção pode estar tomando por base a atividade do software (por exemplo, mexendo em lugares privilegiados do registro, tentando fazer coisas que precisam de privilégio administrativo, criando executáveis em tempo de execução, ou mesmo abrindo serviços de rede em portas privilegiadas). Seria o caso de [edit] e detalhar melhor o que seu software faz e como se comporta, assim como a descrição exata que o antivirus está reportando.

Comment: Sugestão de leitura para melhor aproveitamento do site: [Tour], [Ask] e [Help].

Comment: Você consegue criar um Hello World bem simples e ver se os anti-vírus reclamam dele também? Caso não reclamem, comece a adicionar neste seu Hello World, coisas que o programa faz que poderia fazer o anti-vírus gritar, tais como acessar determinados lugares na rede, ou manipular determinados arquivos, ou acessar o registro, ou iniciar determinados serviço, etc. Não precisa fazer nada de especial com essas coisas, deve ser implementado da forma mais bobinha possível só para ver se o anti-vírus reclama ou não. Assim, você vai conseguir isolar qual é o tipo de coisa que faz o anti-vírus reclamar.

Comment: Victor Stafusa, eu acabei de fazer isso, mas mesmo com um apenas  Hello World, quando eu o executei o Avast já apitou afirmando que o arquivo pode ser perigoso, mas ai depois de analisar rapidamente ele mesmo mostra que não tem perigo.

Comment: Bacco 2, como eu assinaria digitalmente o software? Porque o que eu fiz foi em clicar em propriedades. Nisso aparece as propriedades do programa, e então eu fui em "Signing", depois em "Sign the assembly". Com isso eu criei uma assinatura digital. Seria isso?

Comment: Bacco 2, meu software tem a função de cadastrar, atualizar, buscar e excluir fornecedores e materiais. Para cada fornecedor eu posso cadastrar vários materiais. Apos isso, o software é capas de realizar uns cálculos e gerar um resultado ao usuário.Especificamente, o usuário cadastra cimento, brita, areia e outros materiais e, a partir das características dos mesmos, o programa busca os materiais que foram cadastrados e calcula a quantidade de cada material para gerar 1m³ de concreto. É um programa voltado para engenharia civil.

Comment: Bacco 2, continuando. Para o usuário utilizar as funções de cadastro, atualização e exclusão, eu usei o SQL Server como BD. O programa funciona perfeitamente, porém quando foi abrir o executavel dele o Avast apita imediatamente afirmando que o programa pode ter perigo. Contudo, após alguns segundos de analise, o próprio antivírus informa que não encontrou perigo nenhum. Então fiz exatamente o que o Victor Stafusa me aconselhou, fiz um pequeno programa de "hello word", com apenas uma label e executei, o Avast apitou.